# Android KeyCode Capital Letter?

Tags: android, xml, keyboard, key, keycode

I'm making a soft-keyboard using `XML Keyboard` like this :

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="11.11%p" android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px" android:keyHeight="54dip">

        <Row>
        <Key android:codes="38" android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_ja"
            android:iconPreview="@drawable/iconprev_ja"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="42" android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_nya"
            android:iconPreview="@drawable/iconprev_nya"/>
        <Key android:codes="53" android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_ya"
            android:iconPreview="@drawable/iconprev_ya"/>
        <Key android:codes="46" android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_ra"
            android:iconPreview="@drawable/iconprev_ra"/>
        <Key android:codes="40" android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_la"
            android:iconPreview="@drawable/iconprev_la"/>
        <Key android:codes="51" android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_wa"
            android:iconPreview="@drawable/iconprev_wa"/>
        <Key android:codes="47" android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_sa"
            android:iconPreview="@drawable/iconprev_sa"/>
        <Key android:codes="29" android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_a"
            android:iconPreview="@drawable/iconprev_a"/>
        <Key android:codes="36" android:keyIcon="@drawable/icon_ha"
            android:iconPreview="@drawable/iconprev_ha" />

    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

`android:codes` produces lowercase letters (not capital letters). And http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html does not provide a list of capital letters. How do I fix that?

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to achieve? a) a keyboard with all uppercase letters b) a keyboard with some letters uppercased c) other

Comment: some letter uppercased..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to use one of the modifier keys: `KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT`, `KEYCODE_SHIFT_RIGHT`, or `KEYCODE_CAPS_LOCK`.

EDIT:
You could use `android:keyOutputText` instead of `android:codes`. There you can define any string you wish to output (doesn't even have to be a character).

Comment: Thanks @Zoltán for answer, but i define <Key android:codes="59,29"> (KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT and KEYCODE_A), I must double click and then came A (capital), and if i click other button in my softkeyboard, all capital letter shows (not lowercase letters). how to define it properly?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what you said there. Could you please rephrase?

Comment: Hehe.. sorry, bad english :). KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT = 59, KEYCODE_A = 29 (lowercase). So, i modify my xml : <Key android:codes="59,29">; works, but 'A' show if i double click. How to show 'A' capital single click?

Comment: I dont now, not working for me... If i use that, my soft-keyboard not fully shows. Can u told me keyboard documentation? maybe i can try any attribute.. thanks for help me..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html

Comment: Ok. many thanks @Zoltán, i can try any attribute. If not it could be, I give up :(

Comment: How do you use one of the modifier keys programmatically? The following creates just a lowercase letter: `KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyCode); mDigits.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);`

Answer (score -3):

Android uses standard Ascii keycodes for upper and lower case letters. You will find them here: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/

Comment: That is not true, ASCII codes are not universal and the table you provided is for Windows OS (I think maybe Mac too)